# What is the expected return of a "correctly" priced option if volatility stays constant?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes

For example, if we take a call option on some stock priced using an option pricing model such as Black-Scholes and assume that volatility stays constant and the underlying stock moves according to the assumptions of the model (geometric Brownian motion, constant interest rates, etc.), what can we expect the value of the option to be at expiry?

I'm not sure if there's a clear answer to this, but would appreciate any insight.

Comment: the 'non-arbitrage' price implies that if you were to replicate the option by continuous delta hedging the expectation is that the cost of the option is recouped by the profits from gamma trading. If you simply buy a naked call option and run to expiry the expectation (measured over all final stock prices distribution) is that your total loss is the entire value of the option.

Comment: Black Scholes and the broader topic of risk neutral projection isn't meant to predict future expected values of derivatives. It's meant to provide PVs for the sake of pricing the option. If you want a basic estimate of your option's real world expected return, try the CAPM formula where Beta = (Underlying Beta) * (Option Delta) * (Underlying Price) / (Option Price)